# Divisor problems when it is in the high power format

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the number of **positive integers** which exactly divide **$10^{999}$** but **not $10^{998}$**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$) Every divisor of $10^{998}$ divides $10^{999}$.

$2$) We have $10^{999}=2^{999}5^{999}$, so $10^{999}$ has $(999+1)^2$ positive divisors.

$3$) Similarly, $10^{998}$ has $999^2$ positive divisors.

$4$) The number $1000^2-999^2$ can be computed instantly.

Comment: thank you very much.. it really helpfull

Comment: You are welcome. There are other useful approaches. We can list the numbers that divide $10^{999}$ but not $10^{998}$ explicitly. They are $2^{999}5^k$ and $5^{999}2^k$, $k=0$ to $999$. So $1000+1000$ except we have counted $2^{999}5^{999}$ twice, so $1999$.

Comment: I think you may have hinted at it, but let me add for the original poster that $1000^2-999^2=(1000+999)(1000-999)$.  No calculator required.

Answer (score 1):

$10^{999}=2^{999}5^{999}$, and its divisors are $2^a5^b$ where $0\le a\le 999$ and $0\le b\le 999$.  Now, use this knowledge to determine which divisors do not divide $10^{998}$.

Comment: sorry didnot get it.. can you please elaborate.. it will be very helpful